# Can we attach a module to my Android apk by programmatically? How to achieve this?

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I want to keep my AAR file on my server and when the user wants to add this module in pk, the user should download it, and I want to write such Android code that will provide the user to add a module from my server and attached to the main apk and run it with the same apk.

Answer (score 0):

Upload .aar in aws or jcenter.If .AAR is private must use AWS server.